Error with Lorentz transformation calculation problem
Let second frame move with velocity v relative to rest, and let third move with velocity v' relative to second
when v=0.6(x direction) v'=0.8 (y' direction)
lorentz transformation rest to second is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5/4 & -3/4 & 0 \\
-3/4 & 5/4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
lorentz transformation second to third is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5/3 & 0 & -4/3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-4/3 & 0 & 5/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and lorentz transformation rest to third is product of two matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
25/12 & -5/4 & -4/3 \\
-3/4 & 5/4 & 0 \\
-5/3 & 1 & 5/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but it doesn't look like Lorentz transformation. It isn't symmetry!
What did I do wrong?

Why do you think Lorentz tranformations have to be symmetric?

because Lorentz transformation matrix for arbitrary velocity is symmetric. So I thought my answer should be symmetrical, too

If I remember correctly, composing two boosts in different directions doesn't just produce a boost in another direction but also a rotation of the spatial coordinate axes. And rotation matrices aren't symmetric.

To add onto Andreas Blass's comment, this is the phenomenon of Thomas rotation.

@NicholasTodoroff thank you for your response! I understand it
